# CSS background image make darker

Tags: html, css

I have the following: [www.thewhozoo.com](http://www.thewhozoo.com)

As you can see, it has a background image.

```
.top-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../images/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
  }
```

The background image has white text on top of it, which may be a little difficult to read.

I have added a `text-shadow` to the text, which has helped make the text stand out more.

```
.text-description-header {
    font-size: 250%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 14px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
}
```

However, I would like the text to stand out even more.

**Question**

1. Are there suggestions how I can make the `text-shadow` even darker?
2. Or, make the background image a little darker?

Thanks

Comment: It seems as though you are seeking opinion-based answers. I'm afraid that's off topic here. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi George, not really. I am looking for answers on how to either make the shadow or image darker. Then I will play around with the two options, and use the one I like the most. Pretty straight and technical questions I think.

Comment: you can use overlay with css pseudo element

Comment: no proper title (which explains the issue) => downvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for photoshop to blur the background or give it an overlay. However you can try giving it a linear gradient on your `top-container` class before the url call on the background-image as so:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ),url(../images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

just change the rgba value to what you need. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you. That darker background image looks great. Works for me.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can stack multiple text shadows with `,` to make it darker.

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black, 0px 0px 10px black;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below css for get the same

```
.top-container {
 position:relative;
}

.top-container::before {
 content:'';
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:-1;
}
```