# How to set a semi transparent "picture/image" into black and white, without affecting child elements and background color?

Tags: html, css, image, opacity, transparent

I know that some say that you should use background `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` like that, but that is only for color, not pictures and it also does not remake the picture into black and white.

I am asking for background picture transparency and black and white transformation and I know I could use for example `opacity: 0.5;` for picture background, but that also makes the text withing the box transparent too and it does not make it black and white either.

I only want the background picture of the div box to be semi transparent and transform into black and white at the same time, maybe it is two different codes for it.

**I know of the solution** that I could use 2 div boxes inside each other were one has the semi transparent background and another the text that way not effecting the opacity of one box to the other, but **I wonder if there is a solution to only use one div box for both background and text without effecting the text when using semi transparency plus color or opacity on the background image.**

For example if there was something similar to like:

```
background-opacity: 0.5;
```

or

```
background-image-opacity: 0.5;
```

Although I know that does not exist in CSS, so some solution to that please?

**UPDATE: My CSS used now:**

```
#LinksLayer1
        { position:absolute; left:0px; top:-8px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:3; }

.TDOnLinks
        { font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.TDLinks
        { background-Color: #EEF4FD; background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center; background-image:url('../Pictures/2/P_13.jpg'); }
```

Works well as `#LinksLayer1` is one box (the outer box) that contains `.TDOnLinks` tables and fonts for it, then the `.TDLinks` table is with the background. **But as you understand and I know, it does not give a transparent background.**

**Simplified my HTML and JavaScript code:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function moveover(txt){
    window.status = txt;
}

function fillitin(sitepoints,sitename,Dest,siteextrinfo,sitepage){
    moveover(sitepoints);
    document.SeekLoadLink.sitepoints.value=sitepoints;
    document.SeekLoadLink.sitename.value=sitename;
    document.SeekLoadLink.Dest.value=Dest;
    document.SeekLoadLink.siteextrinfo.value=siteextrinfo;
    document.SeekLoadLink.sitepage.value=sitepage;
    window.setTimeout("prepare()",3500);
}
</script>

<form method="Post" action="" name="SeekLoadLink">


<div id="LinksLayer1">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="TDLinks"><tr><td valign="top" align="center">
Blablabla Head Text

<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="33%" valign="top"><b>**,A,B,C,D,E,F,G</b></td>
    <td width="33%" valign="top"><b>H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O</b></td>
    <td width="33%" valign="top"><b>P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,X,Y,Z</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%" valign="top" class="TDOnLinks"><!-- A,B,C,D,E,F,G -->
Blablabla **,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
    </td><td width="33%" valign="top" class="TDOnLinks"><!-- H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O -->
Blablabla H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
    </td><td width="33%" valign="top" class="TDOnLinks"><!-- P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,X,Y,Z -->
Blablabla LINK  <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF00'; javascript: fillitin('6 &#8722; points','YouTube.com','https://www.youtube.com','Pros & Cons: \n + Has most videos on the net \n &#8722; Little money after 1000 visits \n &#8722; Has too many bad rules.','Gives you very little money for sharing your videos. \nSince January 2018, it only gives money if you have over 1000 visitors per 30 days. \nThey also sometime block and delete videos based on fake copyright claims if you have something society contradicting on the video. Censorship is common.');" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';"><img src="../../Menu_js/imgmini/Link_Icon2.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"> YouTube.com</a><br>

   </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="DivLinkInfo2">
<table height="100%" width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="TEXTLinksMasage" style="direction: ltr;"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" colspan="2">
<nobr><input type="text" name="sitepoints" size="10" class="TEXTLinkPonits" maxlength="255" text value="Ranking" contenteditable="false"><input type="text" name="sitename" size="30" class="TEXTLinkName" maxlength="255" text value="Name" contenteditable="false">URL:<input type="text" name="Dest" class="TEXTLinkPage" size="49" maxlength="255" value="Address" contenteditable="false"></nobr>
</td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="1px">
<Textarea class="TEXTLinkExtraInfo" name="siteextrinfo" cols="28" rows="4" contenteditable="false">

Extra
Inforomation and Pros / Cons
</Textarea>
</td><td align="right" valign="top">
<Textarea class="TEXTLinkInfo" name="sitepage" cols="87" rows="4" contenteditable="false">

Page Resume, Information and Comments...
</Textarea>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
</div>

</form>
```

**NOTE:** I need no font codes for the text in the box, as the box uses the font body CSS already working well. The box only has CSS for background and nothing else. Not even size as the size is regulated by other CSS codes that work. I only need to effect the background in the box, nothing else.

**I tried this:**

```
div.TDLinks:after
        { background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center; background-image:url('../Pictures/2/P_13.jpg'); opacity : 0.5; position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
```

and

```
.TDLinks:after
        { background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center; background-image:url('../Pictures/2/P_13.jpg'); opacity : 0.5; position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
```

But it did not work, what did I do wrong? Could my JavaScript be blocking it?

**NOTE:** I know there are others with similar questions and answers, but it is only similar and not the same question, because nobody has asked of having only one box for this solution with picture background, all the other solutions can be solved by having two div boxes, but I need it all with one div box without effecting the text in that box or they ask of color background and that is a totally different thing.

**NOTE:
This is not a repeat question of this "*Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements*" because that asks of transparent background color, I ask of transparent background PICTURE or IMAGE. Look at the question and its codes plz..**

This question **does not repeat** this one:

[Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438868/css-background-image-make-darker/44439094#44439094

Comment: You'll need to provide the HTML that goes with this CSS in order for anyone to help you. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a pseudo element:

```css
div.bg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

div.bg:after {
  content: "";
  background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a');
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">text here</div>
```

Comment: I tried it like this ``div.TDLinks:after
        {
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-image:url('../Pictures/2/P_13.jpg');
        opacity : 0.5;
        }`` but it did not work

Comment: theres a z-index in my snippet, try again and please post a fiddle with your code if you still need help. https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: your div must have position:relative and the pseudo element must have postion: absolute as you can see in my snippet.

Comment: I always fiddle with the codes I get. Wait let me test with z-index cause that I did not put.

Comment: Test``div.TDLinks
        {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
        }
div.TDLinks:after
        {
  content: "";
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-image:url('../Pictures/2/P_13.jpg');
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;  
        }
``

Comment: It was exactly how you told me and still nothing.

Comment: please send a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I fiddles with it a above and it still does not work. Fact is that if I use ``div.TDLinks`` it does not work at all, but if I use directly ``.TDLinks`` at least it shows the background, but it does not make it semi transparent. And ``div.TDLinks:after`` or ``TDLinks:after`` has no effect at all, I tested them both the exact same way you made with z-index and position. The ``text-transform`` and ``font`` is not needed as the font uses the body css, that I already have and works. But the background is still not semi transparent.

Comment: Thats ok, but I cant help you if I dont see the markup you are using

Comment: As I updated now, I need ot size code as the size is automatically updates by other CSS I have and so is the text fonts. I only need to effect the background in the box, nothing else.

Comment: You'll need to provide the HTML that goes with this CSS in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: I added the answer to your question and now I show what codes I am using for the CSS of that box. As you can see it is pretty much straight forewords, but there are tons of other codes that I can not post here otherwise the entire question would be far too long and complicated. But these are the CSS codes that effect that part of the page.

Comment: Look at the update before saying "You'll need to provide the HTML that goes with this CSS" because that is exactly what I did. You do not need the HTML as the HTML is explained on the text bellow and the HTML is pretty much one box without background inside a box with background and tables and text. The font is applied to the tables and the background to the inner box. The outer box does not have a background since it is made for the scrolling of the page and it does not affect that part I ask of help.

Comment: Just post your entire code as a fiddle dont matter whats the size of your HTML

Comment: Now you got all the codes including the HTML in a simplified way. I can not give you ALL the codes cause that would be far too long. But you have all you need in the update now.

Comment: Trust me if I gave here all the codes in one. It would be far too long and the question would be deleted by the admins. To not mention that all codes are in different files as CSS is a separate file and the JavaScript of the page several separate files too. So lets focus on the problem cause the entire code are far too big for one post.

Comment: There I gave all the essential codes of the page, including the JavaScript, whom should not be effecting the design, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Somebody found the answer here where I missed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements
So I will end this question by giving you the right answer as normally your answer would work, but not in my page for some reason.